# What is the corresponding adjective derived from the verb "misuse"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms, derivational-morphology

From the word *abuse* we can derive the adjective *abusive* by adding the suffix *-ive*.

Can we form an adjective starting from *misuse*? If so, what is the adjectival form of the word *misuse*? Is it *misusive*?

If you think this is not correct, do you have any suggestions, or do you know any synonyms for it that don’t share the same root?

Comment: What about "misused".

Comment: @BillJ I look for something other than gerund or past-participle forms.

Comment: Can you give us an example with context? Knowing how you want to use the word may make it easier to come up with another adjective or a workaround.

Comment: It's an adjective form in, for example, "The often misused word ... ". And it can be modified by "very", as in "a very misused word".

Comment: @BillJ Yes. However, as used in one example in my answer, *a misusive advance* made by a person has, I  believe, a meaning not captured by *a misused advance.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see it in any online dictionary or law dictionary I've checked so far, and the spellchecker here certainly doesn't care for it. However, this adjective is used. Not finding it in a dictionary, I would avoid it for common usage. It's rare in print, but it may be more common in legal language or specialized fields.

> Subsection 245(4) is where the concept of abusive avoidance
> transaction originates but instead of using abusive it uses misuse. The
> simultaneity of the verb misuse and the **adjective** abusive has to be
> acknowledge otherwise most of the subsequent cases would be using
> "**misusive** avoidance transaction" as opposed to "abusive avoidance
> transaction". That would indeed be an uncomfortable outcome. *[Playing
> with Players: The Sacred and Profane Meanderings of a Tax Auditor](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Playing_with_Players/d0H8DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Subsection%20245(4)%20is%20where%20the%20concept%20of%20abusive%20avoidance%20transaction&pg=PA168&printsec=frontcover)*
> (2020) p.168

> ...it has been held that invocation of privilege would be "frivolous"
> or "**misusive**". (1992) [ref](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=misusive)

> Children's awareness and acceptance of their own sexuality will impact
> on their ability to accurately recognize a sexually **misusive**
> advance... [ref](http://Children%27s%20awareness%20and%20acceptance%20of%20their%20own%20sexuality%20will%20impact%20on%20their%20ability%20to%20accurately%20recognize%20a%20sexually%20misusive%20advance) (1990)

> the *speech-language pathologist,* whose responsibility is evaluating
> and treating specific abusive/**misusive** behaviors of the speaking
> voice. *[Voice Therapy](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Treatment_of_Voice_Disorders_Second_Edit/lex6DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=speech-language%20pathologist,%20whose%20responsibility%20is%20evaluating%20and%20treating&pg=PA17&printsec=frontcover)* (2017)

I would normally have read the last example and assumed *misusive* would be found under *misuse.* It's of note that your question and both the first and last examples contrast *misusive* and *abusive.*

Comment: [The OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/120192) provides the following citation: “The wanton misuse, or rather the **misuseful** wantonness, of the Indian herb [*sc.* tobacco].” Derivational morphology seldom holds surprises, and this is not one of them. :)

Comment: @tchrist That's from a letter that can be found in its entirely in *Old Friends: Essays in Epistolary Parody*  https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1991/1991-h/1991-h.htm Just do a page find for *misuseful*-- strangefully, there aren't that many. :)

Answer (score 2):

*Perverse* is probably the closest commonly used adjective.

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/141672?rskey=lKFbXT&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid):

> 1a. Of a person, action, etc.: going or disposed to go against what is
> reasonable, logical, expected, or required; contrary, fickle,
> irrational.
>
> 1906   J. Galsworthy Man of Prop. 72   A distaste born perhaps by the
> perverse processes of Nature out of a secret fund of brutality in
> himself.
>
> 1987   P. Farmer Away from Home (1988) 52   She just says, ‘So what?’
> knowing she is being perverse, but not caring in the slightest.

> 2b. Contrary to an accepted standard or practice; incorrect, mistaken,
> wrong; (of an argument, interpretation, etc.) unjustifiable,
> contradictory, distorted.
>
> 1910   Times 27 Apr. 6/4   This department was open to the imputation
> either of ignorance of the law or of a perverse interpretation of it.
>
> 2000   G. R. Evans Bernard of Clairvaux ii. 36   It would be a
> perverse understanding of the meaning of obedience if a higher duty
> (to do right) was disregarded for the sake of a lower (the duty to
> obey one's abbot).

Answer (score 0):

(I didn't want to add a suggestion to my answer above, or the checkmark might taken as the OP's approval.)

**inept**

> 2: lacking in fitness or aptitude : UNFIT inept at sport
> 3: not
> suitable to the time, place, or occasion : inappropriate often to an
> absurd degree [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inept)

> 1. not suitable to the purpose; unfit [collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/inept)

Used in relation to  *abusive*:

> ...concluded that one-third of those who are abused as children grow
> up to continue a pattern of **inept** or abusive parenting...
> *[Psychoanalytic Therapy After Child Abuse](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Psychoanalytic_Psychotherapy_After_Child/MLJSDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=concluded%20that%20one-third%20of%20those%20who%20are%20abused%20as%20children%20grow%20up%20to%20continue%20a%20pattern%20of%20inept%20or%20abusive%20parenting&pg=PT24&printsec=frontcover)* (2018)

> Another consideration in relation to open confidentiality in work with
> juvenile sexual abusers relates to the need to protect the young
> person from an **inept** or possibly abusive therapist. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Children_and_Young_People_Who_Sexually_A/VybU6vyOZpMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=inept%20abusive&pg=PA137&printsec=frontcover) (2006)